# how to keep fixed height for th

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The height of **th** keeps increasing as the content of **td** increases.How to have a fixed height for **th**.

HTML :

```
<table id="depts">
    <tr>
        <th>Topic Title</th>
        <th><a href="create.php?id=1">ADD TOPIC</a></th>
        <th>Posted By</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuerLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer</td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer  </td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum </td>
    </tr>
        <td colspan="2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer  </td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum </td>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer  </td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
    #depts {
        width: 500px;
        border-spacing: 0;
    }
    #depts a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: white;
        background-color: blue;
        padding: 10px;      
    }
    #depts th {
        border-top: 1px solid black;    
        background-color: #009688;
        text-align: left;
        color: white;
        padding: 5px;
    }
    #depts th:first-child {
        border-left: 1px solid black;
        border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    }
    #depts th:last-child {
        border-right: 1px solid black;
        border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    }
    #depts td {
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
```

When **td** has only one line of content,the output is
[image]

When **td** has multiple lines of content,the output is
[image]

required output:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried various things.Set width of **th** to 33%.This works:

```
    #depts th {
        border-top: 1px solid black;    
        background-color: #009688;
        text-align: left;
        color: white;
        padding: 5px;
        width: 33%;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For the required output you need to use `position: absolute;` on Add Topic button

```
    #depts a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    background-color: blue;
    padding: 20px 10px; 
    position: absolute;
    top: -6px; right: 150px;
    width: 90px;
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gt2q9n5L/ Like this.
This is not perfect, but table layout won't let you to break the borders otherwise.

---

And because it's an table, you need to add ghost column for proper position: absolute styles (if you wesbite is responsive for example)

Answer (score 0):

You should nest your rows with `th` elements inside of a `thead` tag and nest your rows with `td` tags inside of a `tbody` tag as so:

```
<table id="depts">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Topic Title</th>
            <th><a href="create.php?id=1">ADD TOPIC</a></th>
            <th>Posted By</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuerLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer  </td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum </td>
        </tr>
            <td colspan="2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer  </td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum </td>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer  </td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The `thead` tag is used for the table header. The `tbody` tag is used for the table body.

There is also a `tfoot` tag for a table footer.

Hope this helps.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_thead.asp

Answer (score 0):

Using in-line css put style="table-layout:fixed;" or you could put in the css, but this will make text or images overlap into other columns of the width is too small. Don't place long amounts of text or phrases without spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Just an addition of

```
#depts th {
   height: 50px;
}
```

**CODE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    #depts {
        width: 500px;
        border-spacing: 0;
    }

    #depts a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: white;
        background-color: blue;
        padding: 10px;
    }

    #depts th {
        border-top: 1px solid black;
        background-color: #009688;
        text-align: left;
        color: white;
        padding: 5px;
    }

    #depts th:first-child {
        border-left: 1px solid black;
        border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    }

    #depts th:last-child {
        border-right: 1px solid black;
        border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    }

    #depts td {
        border: 1px solid black;
    }

    #depts th {
        height: 50px;
    }
</style>
```

```
<table id="depts">
    <tr>
        <th>Topic Title</th>
        <th><a href="create.php?id=1">ADD TOPIC</a></th>
        <th>Posted By</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer </td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer </td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum </td>
    </tr>
    <td colspan="2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer </td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum </td>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer </td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

This because the `a` element is inline not as block.

Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp

-

You can simply make it block and give it float right if you like.

Here is your original code: https://jsfiddle.net/m52mv11x/

And here is the edited code: https://jsfiddle.net/ss2ksjq7/

I just added this line: `display: block; float: right;` to be like this:

```
#depts a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    background-color: blue;
    padding: 10px;      

    /*This is th just aitional line*/
    display: block; float: right;
}
```

Or you can have `height: 40px;` at `#depts th` like this: https://jsfiddle.net/2raes3dc/

Comment: [https://jsfiddle.net/ss2ksjq7/](https://jsfiddle.net/ss2ksjq7/) still doesn't get required output as shown above.